# Why biased-locking use the different mark word with lightweight-locking

Tags: jvm, locking

When one thread hold a bassed-locking. The mark word is thread id.
But for lightweight-locking, the mark word is stack pointer to the thread, why not store thread id still?

Comment: Looking up a thread id can be non trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Thin lock schema assumes that the mark word of a locked object points to a stack slot of the frame that has locked this object. This stack slot stores the original object header (aka displaced header).

```
    Unlocked:
    [ orig_header | 001 ]       | Stack frame |
                                |             |
    Locked:                     |             |
    [ stack_ptr   | 000 ]       |             |
         |                      |-------------|
          --------------------->| orig_header |
                                |-------------|
                                |             |
                                |             |
                                 -------------
```

Obviously the stack slot carries more information than a thread ID, since you can derive thread ID from a stack slot, but not vice versa.

Unlike biased schema where unlock operation is effectively a no-op, thin locks need to restore the original header when an object is unlocked. This becomes very simple since the mark word already points to a stack slot with the original value.

Comment: You said "Obviously the stack slot carries more information than a thread ID",  but as i know, the stack slot carries information about hashCode and generation age for this object, what would this information be used for thin-locking?

Comment: @user10570334 What I meant is that a stack slot allows you to save and restore the previous object header.

Comment: thin locks need to restore the original header when an object is unlocked, then thin locks will still save the previous object header? what use of this?

Comment: @user10570334 **Locking:** mark word is saved on the stack (so it could be restored later) and then modified with a bit that means "the object is locked" and with a stack pointer to understand which thread has locked this object. **Unlocking:** the mark word is replaced with the previous value that was saved on the stack.

Comment: if thin-locking store thread id, lock: save the thread id which has locked this object. unlock: replace the thread id to -1. why can not be this?

Comment: @user10570334 Java monitors are reentrant: an object can be locked several times recursively. Only the last unlock should reset the header to "unlocked" state.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is to ensure that the hashcode can work when using lightweight/heavyweight locking.

When using biased locking, if you call System.identityHashCode(), the biased locking will inflate to heavyweight locking in order to store the hashcode into the header word.

if lightweight/heavyweight locking also uses the thread id, then there is no place to store the hashcode.

the hashcode and biased locking are exclusive.